# How to open an Excel file in default .xslx app using Java?

Tags: java, excel

I created an excel file using POI but now I need to open it using the default .xslx app (MS Excel in my case). I want to specify that I don't need to parse it or read its contents, but just open it in MS Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after a while, putting this here in case anyone googles it and this page comes up :

```
try {
    File excelFile = new File(filePath);
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(excelFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```